# ¿las propiedades estáticas "existen" en el objeto instanciado?

Tags: php, poo, objeto, class

Tengo una duda teórica. No comprendo precisamente el "lugar espacial" de las propiedades estáticas de una clase. ¿Acaso dejan de existir cuando la clase se instancia? ¿Siempre se hallan en la clase y no son heredadas al instanciar? De instanciar una clase X, ¿las propiedades, variables y métodos que sean estáticos se hallarán en este object instanciado? ¿no tendrían que ser igual de accesibles que las propiedades no-estáticas luego de instanciar, cosa que se niega cuando tratamos de acceder a ambos con `$this`?

No consigo articular la estructura de esto en mi cabeza.

Comment: Las propiedades estáticas existen a nivel de clase, ese es su lugar. Las propiedades no estáticas existen sólo a nivel de instancia, mientras que las propiedades estáticas existen solo nivel de clase. Piensa en propiedades estáticas como variables globales que comparten las clases de un mismo tipo. A esas variables puedes acceder incluso sin crear una instancia, puedes acceder a ellas directamente desde la clase.

Comment: Piensa en el código de tu clase como la fábrica de caramelos, y en tus instancias como los caramelos. Las propiedades estáticas pertenecen a la fábrica de caramelos, no a los caramelos como tal. Por ejemplo, tal vez existe una variable estática en la fábrica de caramelos que cuente los caramelos que se han fabricado hasta el momento. Eso es una variable estática a nivel de clase, no a nivel de instancia. Un caramelo, aunque tiene acceso a la variable, la variable no le pertenece a él cómo tal, pertenece a la fábrica.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez comprendo totalmente. Contrastar que las propiedades no estáticas existen únicamente a nivel instancia fue esclarecedor. Podría decirse pues que las propiedades estáticas son, respecto a las instancias de la clase, meros vínculos, y no están presentes "terrenalmente" como si lo están las propiedades no-estáticas. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las propiedades estáticas existen, pero forman parte de la clase y se comparten entre todos los objetos instanciados desde esa clase, o sea, los pueden acceder pero no con técnicas de instancia ya que no les pertenecen. Debido a que esas propiedades son de la clase, entonces para accederlos hay que referenciar a la clase en si, en vez de usar `$this->var` se usa `self::var`.

En el caso de PHP (cambia entre lenguajes), y corríjanme si me equivoco, crear una *variable* fuera de los métodos, sin usar `static`, es solo declarativo, sigue siendo un atributo de objetos.

En el siguiente ejemplo se declaran 2 variables, una de instancia `$var1` y otra de clase (o estática) `$var2`.

```php
<?php
class MiClase {
    public $var1 = 10;
    public static $var2 = 20;

    function __construct() { }

    public function f1() {
        echo 'var1: ' . $this->var1 . ' | var2: ' . self::$var2 . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public static function f2($v) {
        self::$var2 = $v;
    }
}

$obj1 = new MiClase();
$obj2 = new MiClase();

$obj2->var1 = 11;
$obj2->f2(21);

$obj1->f1(); // Imprime: var1: 10 | var2: 21
$obj2->f1(); // Imprime: var1: 11 | var2: 21
```

Como ves, la propiedad estática `var2` cambió en la clase, lo cual se puede ver reflejado dentro de los objetos. Obviamente como es una propiedad de la clase, se puede cambiar directamente:

```
MiClase::$var2 = 22;
$obj1->f1(); // Imprime: var1: 10 | var2: 22
$obj2->f1(); // Imprime: var1: 11 | var2: 22
```

O también se puede llamar a su método estático.

```
MiClase::f2(30);
$obj1->f1(); // Imprime: var1: 10 | var2: 30
$obj2->f1(); // Imprime: var1: 11 | var2: 30
```

Si se hereda la clase, aún se pueden acceder a las propiedades estáticas de la clase padre:

```
class OtraClase extends MiClase {
    function __construct() { }
}

$obj3 = new OtraClase();
$obj3->f1(); // Imprime: var1: 10 | var2: 30
OtraClase::$var2 = 40;
$obj3->f1(); // Imprime: var1: 10 | var2: 40
```

Comment: Las propiedades estáticas no les pertenecen a las instancias de la misma manera que las propiedades no estáticas únicamente "son" cuando se instancie la clase. Muchas gracias. Una respuesta muy completa.